# different animation for the same event

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The basic idea is that every time that I click the plane will drop a bomb. The moving plane and the dropping bomb are ok, i have two problems:

1) If I drop multiple bombs every explosion animation starts at the same moment of the previous one. Is there is a way to have a different animation for every dropped bomb?

2) I am trying to use `ease("cubic")`, but there is some mistake using it so if possible can you share a tip on how to use it well?

```
let svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = svg.attr("width"),
    height = svg.attr("height"),
    speed = 0.3,
    movement = 600;
let x = 0;
let y = 50;
let w = 100;
let plane = svg.append("svg:image")
    .attr("x", x)
    .attr("y", y)
    .attr("width", 100)
    .attr("height", 100)
    .attr("xlink:href", "b52js.png");
transition();
svg.on("click", function() {
    var bombingx = plane.attr("x")
    let bomb = svg.append("svg:image")
        .attr("x", bombingx - 2.5 + 50)
        .attr("y", y + 50)
        .attr("width", 15)
        .attr("height", 20)
        .attr("xlink:href", "bomb.png");
    bomb
        .transition()
        .duration(1200)
        .attr("y", height - 10)
        .ease("cubic")
        .on("end", function() {
            let exp = svg.append("svg:image")
                .attr("x", bombingx)
                .attr("y", height - 190)
                .attr("height", 250)
                .attr("width", 150)
                .attr("xlink:href", "giphy.gif");
            d3.timer(function(elapsed) {
                exp.remove()
            }, 1500);
            bomb.remove();
        })
});
```

Comment: Your on-event function for the bomb must be defined before the transition. See if that helps.

Comment: nope not solved with this solution

Comment: You said you need different animations for every bomb dropped. How about using multiple gifs and then changing their xlink:href randomly on every click?

Comment: ok that can be an option, but how i can do it? i'm a new in javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to my comment, lets change the `xlink:href` randomly on every click. Gifs of the same dimensions and short length are preferred. Or just create multiple copies of the same gif and put them in the array.

Here's a fiddle:

```js
let svg = d3.select("svg"),
  width = svg.attr("width"),
  height = svg.attr("height"),
  speed = 0.3,
  movement = 600;
let x = 0;
let y = 50;
let w = 100;
let g = svg.append('g').attr('id', 'gg')
let plane = svg.append("svg:image")
  .attr("x", x)
  .attr("y", y)
  .attr("width", 100)
  .attr("height", 100)
  .attr("xlink:href", "https://pngimg.com/uploads/plane/plane_PNG5243.png");
/* transition(); */
svg.on("click", function() {
  var bombingx = plane.attr("x")
  let bomb = svg.append("svg:image")
    .attr("x", bombingx - 2.5 + 50)
    .attr("y", y + 50)
    .attr("width", 15)
    .attr("height", 20)
    .attr("xlink:href", "https://pngimg.com/uploads/bomb/bomb_PNG38.png");
  bomb
    .transition()
    .duration(1200)
    .attr("y", height - 10)
    .ease("cubic")
    .each("end", function() {
      let exp = g.append("g:image")
        .attr("x", bombingx)
        .attr("y", height - 190)
        .attr("height", 250)
        .attr("width", 150)
        .attr("xlink:href", function() {
          // Lets create an array of gif links
          let gifs = ["https://media.giphy.com/media/xA6evoIAtqSzK/giphy.gif", "https://media.giphy.com/media/rkkMc8ahub04w/giphy.gif", "https://media.giphy.com/media/oe33xf3B50fsc/giphy.gif"]

          // A function to return random integers
          function randInt(max) {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
          }


          //randInt(3) will return 0,1 or 2. 
          //This number should be the number of gif links you have in your gif link array.

          return gifs[randInt(3)];
        });

      setTimeout(function() {
        exp.remove();
      }, 1500);
      bomb.remove();
    })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.3.13/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width='300' height='300'></svg>
```

Comment: @claudiogugliotta Glad I could help.